# Magento : how to get the coupon code percent-off amount in the sidebar cart?

Tags: magento, sidebar, coupon

I'm using Magento 1.5.1 and I try to show the total of the cart in the sidebar cart like the checkout/cart page.

I'd like to show the coupon code percent amount if only a coupon has been applied.
For now, I show the cart price with the shipping price but I need this coupon code amount to have the final cart price.

I've just managed to show the coupon code name :

```
$couponCode = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
```

But not its value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find discount, subtotal, shipping, tax and grand total with the code below :

```
// Totals : discount, subtotal, shipping, tax, grand_total
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals();
    foreach($this->getTotals() as $total)
    {
        if ($total->getCode() == 'discount')
        {
            $discount = $total->getValue();
            break;
        }
    } 
?>
```